# L10N localization of numbers in templates using Jinja2 and Django

Tags: django, jinja2

I'm trying to get Jinja2 (and Django, via `django-jinja`) to localize a number, eg. `123456` becomes `123,456` (or, of course, 123.456 depending on the locale). I've read every bit of documentation I can find on the subject, and can't find anything that actually works. Using standard DTL, one could just do:

```
{% localize on %}{{ some_number }}{% endlocalize %}
```

This works fine in my project using regular Django templates, but of course, doesn't work in Jinja2. I mention that this works fine because anything involving `settings.py` such as `USE_L10N` being `False` can be ruled out.

I've tried the following, all based on documentation I've found:

- `{{ gettext("%(num)d", num=some_number) }}` - outputs number with no commas or localization.
- `{% trans num=some_number %}{{ num }} {% endtrans %}` - as suggested by the [django-jinja documentation](http://niwibe.github.io/django-jinja/#_differences) - outputs number with no commas or localization.
- `{{ _(some_number|string) }}` - outputs number with no commas or localization.
- `{{ some_number|localize }}` - `localize` is not a valid filter.

So, how can I easily and properly localize a number using Jinja2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Jinja2 doesn't seem to handle localization on its own, but `django-jinja` includes a built-in contrib that wraps `django.contrib.humanize.templatetags`. According to [the documentation for that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/humanize/), format localization is respected using the `|intcomma` filter if L10n is enabled.

To use it, add `django_jinja.contrib._humanize` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ('django_jinja.contrib._humanize',)
```

And then in templates, simply use the `|intcomma` filter:

```
{{ some_number|intcomma }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it is an old question, I encountered the same found this solution feasible without lot of edits.
[Here](https://github.com/MoritzS/jinja2-django-tags#localization) is library that implements L10n for jinja2 templates. You could integrate it with your application like

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'extensions': [
                'jdj_tags.extensions.DjangoStatic',
                'jdj_tags.extensions.DjangoI18n',
                'jdj_tags.extensions.DjangoL10n',
            ]
        },
    },
}
```